# Eclipse - BEA Workshop issues Help!

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, weblogic, portal

My eclipse workshop keep terminating on me while in the middle of test run or just navigation. Below is the error property i keep getting. Can anyone help stop this nightmare. Thanks

=====
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
C:/bea/jdk150_11/jre/bin/javaw.exe
-Xms384m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Dweblogic.home=C:/bea/wlserver_10.0
-Dosgi.install.area=C:\bea\tools\eclipse32\eclipse
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=C:/bea/user_projects/w4WP_workspaces/Untitled
-Dosgi.configuration.area=C:/bea/workshop_10.0/workshop4WP/eclipse/configuration
-Declipse.product=com.bea.workshop.product.wl.workshop
-Dosgi.splashPath=file:
C:/bea/workshop_10.0/workshop4WP/eclipse/plugins/com.bea.workshop.product.wl_1.0.0
-DprodMode=preProduction
-jar C:\bea\workshop_10.0\workshop4WP\startup.jar
-0s win32
-ws win32
-arch x86
-launcher C:\bea\workshop_10.0\workshop4WP\workshop4WP.exe
-name Workshop4WP
-showsplash 600
-exitdata 154_64
-vm C:/bea/jdk150_11/jre/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Xms384m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Dweblogic.home=C:/bea/wlserver_10.0
-Dosgi.install.area=C:\bea\tools\eclipse32\eclipse
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=C:/bea/user_projects/w4WP_workspaces/Untitled
-Dosgi.configuration.area=C:/bea/workshop_10.0/workshop4WP/eclipse/configuration
-Declipse.product=com.bea.workshop.product.wl.workshop
-Dosgi.splashPath=file:
C:/bea/workshop_10.0/workshop4WP/eclipse/plugins/com.bea.workshop.product.wl_1.0.0
-DprodMode=preProduction
-jar C:\bea\workshop_10.0\workshop4WP\startup.jars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is answered at oracle http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4467747#4467747

Change the JVM setting it looks like JVM is getting crashed out here.
you can use default Jrockit jre for this or and change the heap size for min and max as 1024m.
if you want to use sun JDK then
change the JVM setting as
Max heap as 1024m and min Heap size as 1024 m
permisze as 256 M.
This will resolve your problem.

the ini file can be found:

%BEA_Home%/ workSpaceStudio_1.1\workSpaceStudio\
There is you will see workSpaceStudio.ini
you can change that one.
if it is not a workspace stuido then you will find your ini file under following directory.
%Bea_HOme% / Worksop10 / \workshop4WP/
There you will get the .ini file.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if [this](http://troyworks.com/blog/2008/06/08/eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-1/) can help you.

If memory is your problem, maybe you can attach the jvisualvm tool that ships with the JDK so you can see what's going on in memory as the server runs.

Start your server and note its PID.  Go to your Java /bin, find jvisualvm.exe, and start it up.  You'll have to give jvisualvm the PID of the server process so it can attach to it.  You'll get a nice visual of memory as it's running.  Maybe that will tell you something about what happens when it crashes.

Comment: that didnt help me much. My problem is not that i cant open eclipse. My problem is that eclipse terminates on intermittent basis. Sometimes when am just navigating other times in the middle of a junit test run. I am thinking its a memory allocation problem but dont know how to go about solving it.